# How to use SQL Server Linked server to Sync data between SQL Server & MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, linked-server

I have SQL Server Database on the local machine and MySQL database on the server. Both databases have 100% identical structure. Changes made by software are committing on local database however I want that changes replicated on Server Database (MySQL).

After finding some references for this, I found a way of using **Linked Server** in SQL Server Database.

And I want help on using Linked Server. I have successfully configured Linked Server on my local machine and created System DSN for MySQL but I don't know how to move forward and sync data between two.

I have found similar questions here but none of them have proper answers. I just want to know the one query which will sync between two DBs.

I am hoping this can be achieved using Triggers in MSSQL for each table. Now I know how to write a trigger, I just want to know what to write in the trigger to sync local and server database table.

Let me know if anyone have or know a good article or answer on this. OR a way to sync between SQL Server to MySQL.

Comment: There is no such single sql statement - if there were the other questions on ms sql to mysql sync would already have mentioned it.

Comment: @Shadow: Ok but at least can you give a heads-up doing this. I mean at least how to proceed from this point.

Comment: It would be a lot simpler if both databases were from the same vendor because then you could use the built-in replication solutions.

Comment: I know but that's not the case here. It's strictly MSSQL to MySQL.

Comment: Perhaps you should consider changing the setup. As you can see, the answer provided yo your question is no different from the answers provided to the same question asked here on SO previously.

Comment: @Shadow: I tried searching here so enlighten me and please can you point me to the answers you are referring. Unless I can use those as my answers which I will decide, please not make this duplicate question as you did here.

Comment: Links are displayed on the top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

You have couple of options:

1. Write your own solution using SQL Server Change Data Capture. Example: https://www.dbbest.com/blog/change-data-capture-replication/\
2. Use an open source cross-platform database replication solution. Eg: http://www.symmetricds.org/
3. Or use a paid solution. There are tons of such software. One such product: https://www.hvr-software.com/blog/why-hvr-over-mssql-replication/

It all depends on how critical is the replication, how much data is generated, etc.